# Is there an open source provider of market data?

Tags: financial, trading

Basically I need test data for a trading engine, so don't need real-time data, just something that would give me a reasonable frequency of intra-daily(?) prices.

Comment: Is EUR/USD in MySQL database enough for You? I've got a copy of some forex broker (from FxPro, but I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: @Piotr that would be great.  Would appreciate it very much if you could point me to the data!

Comment: There is a related open source project: http://github.com/kriasoft/market-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just uploaded the file (76MB)

[EUR/USD in MySQL database](http://www.sendspace.pl/file/cac3a163d01458d6311bbe9) - it contains 5 time intervals (1, 5, 15, 30 and 60 minutes)
those are MYISAM tables, so:

1. create some database,
2. turn off MySQL server,
3. copy those file into database folder
4. run the server again

It's located at some polish free file hosting provider server, so if the website won't translate into Your language just click the blue button "Pobierz" (at the bottom-left) to start downloading